# не копируется\перемещается почему-то файл

Tags: java

вот код

```
 public static void MoveFile() {
                try{

                   File afile =new File("C:\\Users\\%UserName%\\Desktop\\tr2.jar");

                   if(afile.renameTo(new File("C:\\Users\\%UserName%\\tr2.jar"))){
                    System.out.println("File is moved successful!");
                   }else{
                    System.out.println("File is failed to move!");
                   }

                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Ошибка вылетает или что?

Comment: ничего не вылетает, просто файл не копируется\перемещается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java не подставит `%UserName%`

Сделайте как-то так:

```
File afile = new File("C:\\Users\\" + System.getProperty("user.name") + "\\Desktop");
```

Comment: спасибо большое